# Does it say anywhere in the tax code that it is a law to pay FEDERAL taxes

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, tax-law

I thought I heard there was one court case of a sovereign citizen who asked the question of the prosecution where in the tax code it says that paying federal taxes is the law. When the prosecution was unable to prove or show that the tax code does say it is a law the defendant won the case. Plus knowing that the writers of the constitution did not want a federal tax imposed why is it now mandatory.

Comment: ha ha, ha ha ha, don't try this yourself, talk to Wesley Snipes first.

Comment: The tax code is literally composed of laws, so the only question as to their authority is whether they are in compliance with the constitution.  Which, as the present answer states, is unambiguously granted by a constitutional amendment.

Comment: If a "sovereign citizen" says something, relying on their advise is very likely to send you to prison.

Answer (score 4):

The US has changed since the eighteenth century, and so the framers wisely made provision for the Constitution to be changed in ways that they themselves might not have envisaged or wanted. The [16th Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixteenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) in 1909 specifically authorised a federal income tax.